# How do you pass data from tableview cell button with a UILongPressGestureRecognizer?

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a button in my cell that if the user holds for a certain length of time it will trigger a popup. I am having trouble passing the cell data with the long press button.

Heres how I submit and pass data with a regular tap...

```
cell.addButton.tag = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row

cell.addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Dumps.addAction(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
```

.

```
@IBAction func addAction(_ sender: Any) {
                
let tag = (sender as AnyObject).tag
            
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: tag!, section: 0)) as! DumpsCell01
        
codeData = cell.codeField.text! }
```

The above works fine.

---

Heres how I submit the button with the long press gesture. Its passing nil through _sender I think

```
cell.deleteButton.tag = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row

let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Dumps.deleteAction(_:)))

cell.deleteButton.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
```

.

```
@objc func deleteAction(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){

let tag = (sender as AnyObject).tag
                
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: tag!, section: 0)) as! DumpsCell01
    
cell.codeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red }
```

How would I pass the data through this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `tag` of the `UIButton` instead of the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` as you have done above.

```
func deleteAction(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let tag = (sender.view as? UIButton)?.tag else { return }
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: tag, section: 0)) as? DumpsCell01
    cell?.codeLabel.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Note: I've also avoided force unwrapping as you should too through-out the project.